# Java I want to print the number of characters in a string

Tags: java

I am working on printing the number of characters taken from a users input. So lets say the user enters `here is a random test` which totals 17 characters. Here is what I have thus far only printing the words in separate lines.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;


public class test {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inputValue;

        inputValue = input.readLine();
        String[] words = inputValue.split("\\s+");

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
           System.out.println(words[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want? What's the question

Comment: Hint: words[i].length() returns the number of characters in one word.

Comment: ok i think that might be enough information.... thanks laune

Answer (score 2):

`str.replaceAll("\\s+","");`removes all whitespaces in `str` and assigns the resultant string to `str`

`str.length()` returns number of characters in String `str`

So when you get the input from user, do this

```
inputValue=inputValue.replaceAll("\\s+","");
System.out.println(inputValue.length());
```

Comment: The tokenized words will never contain spaces. Why not just `System.out.println(inputValue.replaceAll("\\s+","").length());`?

Answer (score 1):

Change your for...loop to this:

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
       total += words[i].length();
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Essentially, we're looping through the array of words, getting each word's length, then adding that number of characters to the total counter.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can avoid iteration over words length if we assume, string is separated by blanks only. Here is an example:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    String test = "here is a random test";
    String[] array = test.split("\\s+");
    int size = array.length > 0 ? (test.length() - array.length + 1) : test.length();
    System.out.println("Size:" + size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the total count you have to assign each words count to a variable. Then print it after for loop.

```
     int count =0;
     for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        count =  count + words[i].length();
     }

     System.out.println(count );
```

Comment: Read my comment before you write an answer.

Comment: Does not compile (String does not respond to `length`)

Comment: @laune, why would/should someone look at your *comment* before writing an answer (silly thing to say after it's already been written but I digress...)? If you feel you've answered the question; *answer* it - in the appropriate place.

Comment: All hail to the @ChiefTwoPencils, but perhaps you didn't see the answer as it was 3 minutes after its posting?

Comment: @laune, don't hail me please. I was asking an honest question after reading this comment and the one you're referring to. I don't understand the timeline you speak of.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Well, at that time there was a syntax error in this A which abc could have avoided by just that: reading my comment. See comments #2 and #3. Yes, I could have -1-ed and left. Ours is the aim to make this grand site grander! ;-)

Comment: @laune, yes I thought that was a possibility. Another can of worms are being opened after that. I wouldn't -1 for syntactical errors by default either, my goal is the same - hence the comment about perhaps providing an answer yourself ;) length vs. lenght(), IMHO, is trivial to the question of did they point the ask-er in the right direction; a trait I learned here.

Comment: I'd rather just give a hint and let OP's brain work it out, which appears to have worked here (3rd comment to Q). - Too many here are just greedy for points.

Answer (score 0):

Fewmodification done,

length printed for words and user input.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inputValue;

        inputValue = input.readLine();
        String[] words = inputValue.split("\\s+");

        System.out.println("Length of user input = " + inputValue.length());

        for (int i = 0 ; i < words.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println(words[i]);
            System.out.println("Length of word = " + words[i].length());
        }

    }
```

**Output**

```
here is a random test
Length of user input = 21
here
Length of word = 4
is
Length of word = 2
a
Length of word = 1
random
Length of word = 6
test
Length of word = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you are concerned only with whitespaces:

```
inputValue = input.readLine();
int len = inputValue.replaceAll(" ", "").length(); //replacing won't effect the original string and will also replace spaces.
System.out.println(len);
System.out.println(inputValue);
```

so the o/p would be for sample you provided:

```
17
here is a random test
```